# Override 'new' with a pool allocator; return NULL?

Tags: c++

Is there a way to *not* call a class constructor if operator new returns null?

Consider this class C:

```
class C {
    public:
        C() { printf("%p->C()\n", this); }
        ~C() { printf("%p->~C()\n", this); }

        static void* operator new(std::size_t sz) {
            printf("new!\n");
            return NULL;
        }
};

int main()
{   
    C* c = new C();
    printf("new C returns %p\n", c);
    return 0;
}
```

When I run I get this:

```
new!
0x0->C()
new C returns 0x0
```

So I can make new return NULL but it still calls the constructor with a null 'this' pointer.  Is there any way to write my own allocator that allocates memory, explicitly calls the c'tor if possible, then returns?

Thanks!

Comment: But new doesn't normally return NULL if it fails - normally it throws std::bad_alloc doesn't it?

Comment: The implementation of `operator new` that returns a nullptr is incorrect. An allocation function must signal failure by throwing `std::bad_alloc` unless it's declared as non-throwing.

Comment: So there's absolutely no way to force it to return NULL and *not* try to call the constructor?

Comment: @Eric: You can declare it as `noexcept` and upgrade your compiler.

Answer (score 2):

Returning a null pointer from an `operator new` means allocation failed, but only if the function is declared `noexcept`, otherwise the function most throw a `std::bad_alloc` (or something derived from it).

As it stands your program has undefined behavior, if you add `noexcept` you should find the constructor isn't called as the function now correctly signals that allocation failed.

```
static void* operator new(std::size_t sz) noexcept
```

[basic.stc.dynamic.allocation]

> 1. An allocation function shall be a class member function or a global function;[...]

> 3. [...] If an allocation function that has a non-throwing exception specification (15.4) fails to allocate storage, it shall return a null pointer. Any other allocation function that fails to allocate storage shall indicate failure only by throwing an exception (15.1) of a type that would match a handler (15.3) of type `std::bad_alloc` (18.6.2.1).